# CSS - How make cursor : pointer when hover a parent which is an another component in ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to push some interactivity in nested component in ReactJS.

[Here a snippet to test the code](https://codesandbox.io/s/m33yr6k4py).

Here my NesterComponent.js :

```
<div {a general div}> 
      <div className={style.displayer} > 
        <IncludedComponent/> 
      </div>
</div>
```

here my IncludedComponent.js:

```
    <div>
          <div className={style.dish_footer}>
              <div onClick={this.addArticle} className={style.add}> // this is the div that I want to style and add some interactivity on, it's a pretty greatly nested div ^^ </div>
          </div> 
   </div>
```

then you obtain something like this:

[image]

How add CSS hovering in a such nested div ? any hint would be great,
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.parent:hover .child {
cursor:pointer;
}
```

you can import this css in either the parent or child component.

[Here a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/n5w648rx9p).

EDIT:  seeing you just want the nested component to have the hover effect.  here is the jsx you should use for the nested component

```
<div className="parent">
      <div className={style.dish_footer}>
          <div onClick={this.addArticle} className={style.add + " child"}>
          </div>
      </div>
```

now include the css above and don't worry about the nesting.  in css you just select the class you want to hover,  and the child class you want to style when that parent is hovered.

Comment: so you would need to add static classNames to both components.

Comment: thanks for answering Ben Hart, my difficulty is that I want to specifically the hover being triggered when I hover lonely the nested component and nothing else. With `.parent:hover .child {
cursor:pointer;
}`  is the whole parent's div which is summoned and not just the part I target :/

Comment: Okay thanks, I will release a Sandbox snippet meanwhile

Comment: Your code doesn't works for me,  you can test on the snippet

Comment: effectively, so it would be the fact that my nested component is also in `position:fixed` that cause theses difficulties

Comment: I have found that was my z-index which make all fail, it was a negative z-index